# Lumen: BrowserSync with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, lumen, browser-sync, lumen-5.8

I can't get working BrowserSync with Laravel Mix on a Lumen project. It's a fresh install.

As explained on Lumen docs, I launch the server with:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Opening the path `localhost:8000` the project correctly works.

Then add BrowserSync in `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'dist/js')
   .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'dist/css')
   .browserSync('localhost:8000'); //<== Added this
```

Then launch the `watch` with:

```
npm run watch
```

It opens the browser on the page `localhost:3000` but it remains in loading (white page). At `localhost:3001` I can see BrowserSync interface that correctly list:

```
Proxying:
http://localhost:8000
```

Tried to launch the PHP server with IP instead of `localhost`

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public
```

and it seems work but I'm not sure it's the right way. All around the web it's used with `localhost`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It worked for me using `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public` but I don't think it's right. Any news about it?